# KERNER INSTALL error in VS CODE using ipynb file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel, vscode-extensions

[I am getting this ERROR or message whenever I am running my commands on my ipynb file. Please HELP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjruS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Sc4h.png)

Comment: so what's the error message?

Comment: Do you have Python installed on your PC? If yes, after adding the Jupyter extension to VS Code restart VS Code. When running a cell, VS Code will list the Python versions that have been installed on your PC. You can choose one of them.

Comment: And please be specific if the issue you are facing is an error or not. Describe your issue as it is.  In your case, it is not an error but something related to configuration.

Comment: Please, do not use images for represent the text. Instead, copy paste the **text** (the code, the error message) into the question post itself. See also [ask].